# ASP.NET Web Service template not exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, .net-4.0

I have a full installation of **Visual Studio 2010** with **.Net framework 4**. I want create my first web service. but not exist **web service** template.
In visual studio 2010  I go to **File** -> **New Web Site** menu , but in the **New Web Site** dialog box not exist **ASP.NET Web Service** template.

[image]

How to create a Web Service?

Comment: Create an empty website first and add webservice to it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use File->New Project->WCF Service Application.

"ASP.NET Web Services" (aka ASMX) is a legacy technology. It exists only to support existing ASMX services. Do not use it for new development.

Answer (score 6):

create ASP.net Empty Web Site and add asmx file. that's it.

Or You can Target the .Net Framework to 3.5 when you create the project and web service template available for .net 3.5, create the project and re target it to 4.0 or 4.5

But You better move to [Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx)

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: In the real commercial world, it's not always that feasible to simply ditch old-hat technology.  The developer if very often simply stuck with it for whatever commercial, political or pragmatic reason.

Comment: Simply saying "it can't be done anymore" when it can is a horrid answer.  This is the true answer here.

Answer (score 4):

Go to File --> New -->Asp.Net Empty Web application.
on that Right click --> Add New item - >webservice template

Answer (score 0):

```
File > New Project > Visual C# > Web Service Application
```

You can create multiple projects under one solution..
create a web service,build and run it.
Then create another webapplication under the same solution file.
Add reference..
Thats it..

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: For God's sake, get down off your high horse and join the real World. There are so many valid reasons for maintaining existing, older projects. There is no reason to pontificate to people left, right and center. We're here to answer people's problems not to lecture them.