# Web Service template missing from Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2015

I've been tasked with creating a custom web service for a client solution. I've recently installed Visual Studio Pro 2015 and I can't seem to find the template for an .asmx Web Service. I remember it used to be in VS 2013 Premium. Do I need a different version of VS 2015? Is there a way I can import the template?

Comment: i have not seen it after 2008

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Web Service template not exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023487/asp-net-web-service-template-not-exist)

Comment: Do you need it to be a soap service?  Soap is kind of dead.  You could use WebApi2 instead, it's a lot nicer and easier to use imo.  Unless the client expects a Soap Service.  In other words, use WebApi2 and build a rest web service, they are way easier to call in JS layers, and simpler to implement, also much faster performance wise as the payloads are drastically smaller.

Answer (score 70):

This is answered under  [ASP.NET Web Service template not exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24983942/6937776), but to reiterate

Make sure that you set the Framework to .NET Framework 3.5 or you won't find the Asp.Net Empty Web application.

Go to File --> New -->Asp.Net Empty Web application. On that Application Right click --> Add --> New item - > Web Service (ASMX).

OR

Right click on your Solution --> Add --> New Project --> confirm you are set on .NET framework 3.5 --> Visual C# or Visual Basic -->Asp.Net Empty Web application. Name project.  On that project Right click --> Add --> New item - > Web Service (ASMX).

For the naysayers. Answer the question. Don't berate the Poster. If you have a better idea then tell the Poster how or link the Poster to the a tutorial. Stop displacing your anger on others.

I am stuck in the same bind. Customer wants to dump a post to an ASMX. I talked to them, but this is how they have always done it and they won't change. Sometimes ya gotta do what ya gotta do. Just rub the zombie gore on yourself and wander through the zombie horde. BRAINSSSS

Comment: Your point in your Answer is spot-on.  Some devs are supporting enterprise mission-critical applications that use ASMX.  They don't have the option of changing the paradigm and adding a new web service to 20 web services already in place and have that web service use a different technology or framework simply because the technology is newer.

Comment: Just have to say, SO is full of people that instead of just answer a person's question, berate the user for not taking a different approach or using a newer technology.  +1 to the answer and comment above.

Comment: Thank you Rourke. Great answer and you read my mind as I read the other answer(s).   As you say, there are usually valid, pragmatic, real-world reasons for persisting with a seemingly obsolete framework.  They can't use the latest whizz-bang technology because they can't.  Much development involves simply protecting the investment.

Comment: Yes, there are still reasons to use this. We are having to implement a Web Service that a third party API uses. It has to be in SOAP and follow their WSDL, otherwise we cannot integrate with them. Note we build the service on our website that they then call into

Comment: OK, now I have read more, I have found that you can use the wsdl to implement a WCF service fairly easily, so you are then not restricted to 3.5 e.g. http://scrumsofanarchy.com/reverse-engineering-a-soap-web-service-in-net-wcf-2/

Comment: After following these steps I was able to change the target framework to 4.5.2 (in My Project) and still run the basic "Hello World" web service. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023541/381082

Comment: PabloInNZ, they have updated their URL:
http://scrumsofanarchy.com/2018/04/07/reverse-engineering-a-soap-web-service-in-net-wcf/

Answer (score 6):

You have to select .NET Framework 3.5 or lower.

I'm kind of wondering why you would make a .asmx web service in a new project?  That's hasn't been supported by Microsoft in a long time.  And WCF is far superior.  And Web API is far superior to WCF.

Comment: +1 for web api, that's what I mentioned in my comment above.  In WebApi2 you can write a full web service with a database backend in less than an hour once you know what you are doing.  Soap is dead (well it's undead), as in it won't die, but it should.

Comment: @Ryios - LOL! undead

Comment: may be for a PlayReady License server :)

Comment: SOAP is still used very heavily in industries like finance. We work with banks and there is no way of getting them away from the strict contractual comms that it provides any time soon.

Comment: not convinced you need to have such an old version.. i just managed to create this is 4.6.1 .. seemed fine.

Answer (score 2):

Set the Framework to .NET Framework 3.5

Then:
Go to File Menu --> **Add** --> **New Web Site** --> set the Framework to .NET Framework 3.5 --> **ASP.NET Web Service**