# Web Service - SoapClient not in assembly reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, uwp, soap-client

I am doing some course work and am extremely confused as the course uses seemingly the same names for different things.

It creates a web service and then this application consumes it and displays the result.

The web service has a method called `MBCProductDetails()`
The actual service reference in the app consuming it is also called MBCProductDetails

This is the Code the Course gives me to consume it -

```
private async void btnGetRates_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MBCProductDetails.MBCProductDetailsSoapClient serviceMBCProductDetails = new MBCProductDetails.MBCProductDetailsSoapClient();

    MBCProductDetails.GetProductDetailsResponse MBCProductDetailsResponse = await serviceMBCProductDetails.GetProductDetailsAsync(Convert.ToInt32(txtProductCode.Text));

    tbProductNameValue.Text = "Product: " + MBCProductDetailsResponse.Body.GetProductDetailsResult.ProductName;
    tbInterestRateValue.Text = "Interest Rate: " + MBCProductDetailsResponse.Body.GetProductDetailsResult.InterestRate.ToString();
    tbAccountKeepingFeeValue.Text = "Account Fee: " +  MBCProductDetailsResponse.Body.GetProductDetailsResult.AccountFee.ToString();

}
```

Now I am trying to do this myself but when I do i get `MBCProductDeatilsSoapClient does not exist in the namespace.`

Could anybody run me through exactly what is going on here, which names go where and such because I am thoroughly confused. Cheers

Edit:

This is the code from the Web Service

```
public struct ProductDetails
{
    public int ProductCode;
    public string ProductName;
    public double InterestRate;
    public double AccountFee;
}

private ProductDetails Products;

public MBCProductDetails()
{
    Products.ProductCode = 0;
    Products.ProductName = "";
    Products.InterestRate = 0;
    Products.AccountFee = 0;
}

private void AssignValues(int ProductCode)
{

    Products.ProductCode = ProductCode;

    if (ProductCode == 1)
    {
        Products.ProductName = "Everyday Loan Account";
        Products.InterestRate = 4.5;
        Products.AccountFee = 10;
    }
    else if (ProductCode == 2)
    {
        Products.ProductName = "Business Loan Account";
        Products.InterestRate = 3.5;
        Products.AccountFee = 12;
    }
    else if (ProductCode == 3)
    {
        Products.ProductName = "Offset Loan Account";
        Products.InterestRate = 5.0;
        Products.AccountFee = 15;
    }
    else
    {
        Products.ProductName = "Loan Account not found";
        Products.InterestRate = 0.0;
        Products.AccountFee = 0;
    }
}

[WebMethod(Description = "This method call will get the product name, interest rate and the account fee for a given product code.", EnableSession = false)]
public ProductDetails GetProductDetails(int ProductCode)
{
    AssignValues(ProductCode);
    ProductDetails RequestedProductDetails = new ProductDetails();
    RequestedProductDetails.ProductCode = Products.ProductCode;
    RequestedProductDetails.ProductName = Products.ProductName;
    RequestedProductDetails.InterestRate = Products.InterestRate;
    RequestedProductDetails.AccountFee = Products.AccountFee;
    return RequestedProductDetails;
}
```

Comment: What is MBCProductDetails?

Comment: @lindexi in this case it is the name of the Method in the Web Service itself and also the name of the web reference. I will add the other code above for you.

Answer (score 0):

> The web service has a method called MBCProductDetails()

Inside the web service, the `MBCProductDetails()` here should be the [Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) method for `MBCProductDetails` class.So that the web service class should be `MBCProductDetails`, the complete struct for web service should be like follows:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MBCProductDetails : System.Web.Services.WebService
{ 
    [WebMethod(Description = "This method call will get the product name, interest rate and the account fee for a given product code.", EnableSession = false)]
    public ProductDetails GetProductDetails(int ProductCode)
    {
     ...
    }
    public MBCProductDetails()
    {
     ...
    }
    public struct ProductDetails
    {
      ...
    }
    private ProductDetails Products;
    private void AssignValues(int ProductCode)
    { 
    ...
    }
}
```

> Now I am trying to do this myself but when I do i get MBCProductDeatilsSoapClient does not exist in the namespace.

On the UWP client side, for code line `MBCProductDetails.MBCProductDetailsSoapClient`, here the `MBCProductDetails` should be the namespace of the added service reference. By default the namespace is `ServiceReference1`, if you want to use the above client code snippet you need to rename it to  `MBCProductDetails` as following picture showed, otherwise you will get the "does not exist" exception since there isn't a service reference namespace named `MBCProductDetails`.
[image]

Ensure that you have `MBCProductDetails` inside the connected service after the service reference added.

[image]

The testing result on my side:

[image]

Additionally, I recommend you to use WCF service instead since "ASP.NET Web Services" (aka ASMX) is a legacy technology. Details you may reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023487/asp-net-web-service-template-not-exist/24983942#24983942).